# WYSIWYG text editor widget on iOS app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, wysiwyg

Are there any implementations (open source or proprietary) of TinyMCE-like widgets for iOS apps?

If not, are there any references, tutorials, recipes etc no how to roll one's own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DTRichTextEditorView](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/rich-text-editing-on-ios/) from Cocoanetics is currently in beta.

Comment: Just in case anyone gets excited, I'll note that this suggestion is alas not Open Source.

Answer (score 5):

I just released [ZSSRichTextEditor](https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor) as well. Beautiful iOS7 style WYSIWYG editor.